# How to pass variable values to sendKeys in casperjs

Tags: casperjs, sendkeys

I have the following issue with sendKeys in casperjs.
I am trying to pass the port as an option into casperjs and this is working, but when i try to use the port value with casper.cli.get it doesn't work in sendKeys!!!

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.echo("Casper CLI passed args:");
require("utils").dump(casper.cli.args);

casper.echo("Casper CLI passed options:");
require("utils").dump(casper.cli.options);

if (casper.cli.has("ip") === false) {
  casper.echo("Usage: casper.js test modify_port.js --ip=<x.x.x.x> --port=<xxxxx>").exit();
}
if (casper.cli.has("port") === false) {
  casper.echo("Usage: casper.js test modify_port.js --ip=<x.x.x.x> --port=<xxxxx>").exit();
}
...
    casper.then(function() {
        test.assertTextExists("Change", "Data Base - Change - port");
        this.sendKeys('input[name="Params.port"]', casper.cli.get("port"));
        this.click('input[name="Apply"]');
    });
```

The above way seems not to work and it doesn't give me also no error msg.
But when i hard code the port in the sendKeys line then i see that the port is changed, like:

```
this.sendKeys('input[name="Params.port"]', '29999');
```

This is also working fine (hard coded):

```
var myPort = '29999'
this.sendKeys('input[name="Params.port"]', myPort);
```

But this again is not working:

```
var myPort = casper.cli.get("port")
this.sendKeys('input[name="Params.port"]', myPort);
```

Thanks in adv. for your time

Comment: Hi all, i just got it **this.sendKeys('input[name="Params.port"]', casper.cli.raw.get('port'));***! Thanks again

Comment: Please write an answer yourself and accept it (8 hours later). Don't forget to write, why this was a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more readings I stepped over the part where casperjs documentation is saying about Raw parameter values.

So, I figured out to use my parameter in this way:

```
this.sendKeys('input[name="Params.port"]', casper.cli.raw.get('port'));
```

Answer (score 1):

When passing variables into sendKeys they will not appear in the form unless they are preceded with an empty string "".

```
this.sendKeys("selector", "" + variable);
```

I guess this may be because sendKeys can only handle variables of type string.

[Source](http://www.sizenote.info/blog/?p=55)